# Plotting one segment of 4 signals on same line/channel in one subplot using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I downloaded this ECG [data](https://physionet.org/content/ecg-arrhythmia/1.0.0/) from physioNet and applied some signal processing techniques over it. And now I want to visualize them so they appear like this (segment of 4 signals on each line/ channel except for the last channel) and I don't know how or at least where to search for:

[image: the needed plot]

instead of this:

[image: my trial]

and in this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Wpp-kHslyJU1a6hPJ5ppIabZxR_nikQK?usp=drive_link)  you can find a sample of the data I am visualizing.

```
data=("D:\Matlab\a-large-scale-12-lead-electrocardiogram-database-for-arrhythmia-study-1.0.0\a-large-scale-12-lead-electrocardiogram-database-for-arrhythmia-study-1.0.0\WFDBRecords\01\010\JS00001.mat");
x=load('JS00012.mat');
y = x.val/2000;
y = y';
fs=500;
t = (0:length(y)-1)/fs; % Time vector
% Assuming you have 12 signals stored in the variable 'y'

% Create separate variables for each signal
signal1 = y(:, 1);
signal2 = y(:, 2);
signal3 = y(:, 3);
signal4 = y(:, 4);
signal5 = y(:, 5);
signal6 = y(:, 6);
signal7 = y(:, 7);
signal8 = y(:, 8);
signal9 = y(:, 9);
signal10 = y(:, 10);
signal11 = y(:, 11);
signal12 = y(:, 12);

fcutlow = 0.5; % Lower cutoff frequency in Hz
fcuthigh = 40; % Upper cutoff frequency in Hz
[b,a] = butter(4, [fcutlow/(fs/2) fcuthigh/(fs/2)], 'bandpass');
filtered_signal = zeros(size(y));
for i = 1:size(y, 2)
    filtered_signal(:,i) = filtfilt(b, a, y(:,i));
end

% Amplify the filtered signal data
amplified_signal = 2 * filtered_signal;

% Apply baseline correction to each lead of the filtered signal data
baseline_corrected_signal = zeros(size(amplified_signal));
for i = 1:size(amplified_signal, 2)
    baseline_corrected_signal(:,i) = amplified_signal(:,i) - medfilt1(amplified_signal(:,i), fs/4);
end

% Apply wavelet denoising to each lead of the amplified signal data
denoised_signal = zeros(size(baseline_corrected_signal));
for i = 1:size(baseline_corrected_signal, 2)
    denoised_signal(:,i) = wden(baseline_corrected_signal(:,i),'minimaxi','s','mln',8,'sym4');
end

% Create separate variables for each signal
signal_clean1 = denoised_signal(:, 1);
signal_clean2 = denoised_signal(:, 2);
signal_clean3 = denoised_signal(:, 3);
signal_clean4 = denoised_signal(:, 4);
signal_clean5 = denoised_signal(:, 5);
signal_clean6 = denoised_signal(:, 6);
signal_clean7 = denoised_signal(:, 7);
signal_clean8 = denoised_signal(:, 8);
signal_clean9 = denoised_signal(:, 9);
signal_clean10 = denoised_signal(:, 10);
signal_clean11 = denoised_signal(:, 11);
signal_clean12 = denoised_signal(:, 12);
figure;
subplot(4,4,1);
hold on;
grid on;
plot(t(1:5*fs), denoised_signal(1:5*fs,1));
box off;
set(gca,'XColor','none','YColor','none', 'Color', [1, 1, 1]);
hold off;

subplot(4,4,2);
hold on;
grid on;
plot(t(1:5*fs), denoised_signal(1:5*fs,4));
box off;
set(gca,'XColor','none','YColor','none', 'Color', [1, 1, 1]);
hold off;

subplot(4,4,3);
hold on;
grid on;
plot(t(1:5*fs), denoised_signal(1:5*fs,7));
box off;
set(gca,'XColor','none','YColor','none', 'Color', [1, 1, 1]);
hold off;

subplot(4,4,4);
hold on;
grid on;
plot(t(1:5*fs), denoised_signal(1:5*fs,10));
box off;
set(gca,'XColor','none','YColor','none', 'Color', [1, 1, 1]);
hold off;

subplot(4,4,5);
hold on;
grid on;
plot(t(1:5*fs), denoised_signal(1:5*fs,2));
box off;
set(gca,'XColor','none','YColor','none', 'Color', [1, 1, 1]);
hold off;

subplot(4,4,6);
hold on;
grid on;
plot(t(1:5*fs), denoised_signal(1:5*fs,5));
box off;
set(gca,'XColor','none','YColor','none', 'Color', [1, 1, 1]);
hold off;

subplot(4,4,7);
hold on;
grid on;
plot(t(1:5*fs), denoised_signal(1:5*fs,8));
box off;
set(gca,'XColor','none','YColor','none', 'Color', [1, 1, 1]);
hold off;

subplot(4,4,8);
hold on;
grid on;
plot(t(1:5*fs), denoised_signal(1:5*fs,11));
box off;
set(gca,'XColor','none','YColor','none', 'Color', [1, 1, 1]);
hold off;

subplot(4,4,9);
hold on;
grid on;
plot(t(1:5*fs), denoised_signal(1:5*fs,3));
box off;
set(gca,'XColor','none','YColor','none', 'Color', [1, 1, 1]);
hold off;

subplot(4,4,10);
hold on;
grid on;
plot(t(1:5*fs), denoised_signal(1:5*fs,6));
box off;
set(gca,'XColor','none','YColor','none', 'Color', [1, 1, 1]);
hold off;

subplot(4,4,11);
hold on;
grid on;
plot(t(1:5*fs), denoised_signal(1:5*fs,9));
box off;
set(gca,'XColor','none','YColor','none', 'Color', [1, 1, 1]);
hold off;

subplot(4,4,12);
hold on;
grid on;
plot(t(1:5*fs), denoised_signal(1:5*fs,12));
box off;
set(gca,'XColor','none','YColor','none', 'Color', [1, 1, 1]);
hold off;

subplot(4,4,[13,14,15,16]);
hold on;
grid on;
plot(t(1:5*fs), denoised_signal(1:5*fs,2));
box off;
set(gca,'XColor','none','YColor','none', 'Color', [1, 1, 1]);
hold off;

xlabel('Time (s)');

sgtitle('Denoised Signals');
```

Comment: This question would be improved by an [edit] which removed the dependency on downloading your data from an external source to instead have a self-contained [mcve] which we can run without any dependencies (i.e. using random data). You can either re-position the subplot axes to remove the whitespace between them, or stitch the signals on each row together on a single axis and just have one column of subplots